# How to get types from IFC objects

Tags: javascript, ifc

Both by using `getSpatialStructure` and using `getIfcType` I get back strings like `'IFCDOOR'`
But all functions that want types are expecting some int ([395920057 for IFCDOOR](https://github.com/IFCjs/web-ifc-three/blob/d133f84181fd10a70ad3e5c0b93b52bf3d330989/web-ifc-three/src/IFC/components/IfcTypesMap.ts#L214))

How can I convert the string to an int, or alternatively get the int from the mentioned APIs directly?

Answer (score 0):

All the numeric values assigned to IFC types can be found in [web-ifc](https://github.com/ifcjs/web-ifc) as constants whose name is the name of the IFC type. For instance, if you want to get the numeric value assigned to IFC door, you can do the following:

```
import { IFCDOOR } from 'web-ifc';
```

Comment: Weird, so if I'm trying to iterate over the model and get all it types I need to import in the middle of the code?

Comment: I found ifcLoader.ifcManager.typesMap has the opposite of what I want, so I thought I can pivot this object and get the map I need

Comment: Yep, web-ifc has no method to iterate over the types yet, but if you create an issue, we'll add it!